# Update checkboxes from database after actionbutton is clicked in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

I'm creating a shiny app that will get values from a database table and update the other upon user request. The problem arises once the add button is clicked. The checkboxes hold the same value as earlier and do not get the new values from database.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Available names", td),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup2", "Present names",c(ch1,ch)),
  actionButton("action", label = "Add")
)
```

td, ch1 and ch are lists gathered from the database.

```
z <- NULL    
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # checkbox listener
  observe({
    x <- input$inCheckboxGroup
    y <- NULL

    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)

    # Get the names for these ids
    for (i in x){
      y <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(conn, paste0("--sql query--") ))
      z <- c(z,y[,1])
    }

    # Print the names from previous block into the checkboxes
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup2",
                             choices = c(ch1,z),
                             selected = z)
  })

  # button listener
  observeEvent(input$action,{
    for(i in input$inCheckboxGroup){
      rs <- dbSendQuery(conn, paste0("--sql query--"))
      dbFetch(rs)
    }
    showNotification("Row inserted")
  })
}
```

What I tried was to create a page refresh functionality or input reset that would do the trick. But even reloading the page does nothing. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Why is there no `updateCheckboxGroupInput` in the `observeEvent` for the action button being clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the check boxes once the button is pushed so the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` needs to be in the `observeEvent` for the action button. Below is an example of how to do so.

```
library(shiny)

td<-c(1,2,3)
ch1<-c(1,2,3)
ch<-c(1,2,3)


ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Available names", td),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup2", "Present names",c(ch1,ch)),
  actionButton("action", label = "Add")
)

server<-function(input,output,session){

  # button listener
  observeEvent(input$action,{
    database<-c(4,5,6)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"inCheckboxGroup", choices = database)
    })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

If trying to update the values of the check boxes, do a similar command but used `selected`. Also below is how to update both sets of checkboxes.

```
  # button listener
  observeEvent(input$action,{
    database<-c(1,3)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"inCheckboxGroup", selected=database)
    #For the Second group simply call the other label
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"inCheckboxGroup2", selected=database)
    })

 }
```

[image]

Comment: That worked for the first checkbox group but the second one (present names) does not update. Does this have to do with the `observe` function because once the button is clicked, the second checkboxes are not updated wrt to the first checkboxes?

Comment: The second group of check boxes would need a `updateCheckboxInput` call as well. Meaning the same code but with `"inCheckboxGroup2"` instead.

Comment: Just put the call to the second group of check boxes under the same observe event so that when the button is pushed both groups are updated.

Comment: That's exactly what I did which caused the above mentioned (failure to update).

Comment: I am guessing this has to do with the previous call made in the "# checkbox listener", as this is resetting any update made. Get rid of that `updateCheckboxInput` in that section.